# recursively flatten objects in nested objects and arrays javascript

Tags: javascript, json, recursion, flatten

I have a big JSON object that can be irregular, what I want is to find a way to put all of its objects in a flat array.

this is an example json:

```
{
    "name":"getPost",
    "request":{
        "type":"object",
        "fields":[{
            "key":"id",
            "value":{"type":"string"}
        }]
    },
    "response":{
        "type":"object",
        "fields":[{
            "key":"post",
            "value":{
                "type":"object",
                "fields":[{
                    "key":"id",
                    "value":{"type":"string"}
                },{
                    "key":"title",
                    "value":{"type":"string"}
                },{
                    "key":"content",
                    "value":{"type":"string"}
                },{
                    "key":"userId",
                    "value":{"type":"string"}
                }]
            }
        }]
    },
    "error":[]
}
```

and I want it to become something like this:( I only need objects that have shallow key-values)

```
[
    {
        "key":"id",
        "value":{"type":"string"}
    },{
        "key":"post",
        "value":{"type":"object"}
    },{
        "key":"id",
        "value":{"type":"string"}
    },{
        "key":"title",
        "value":{"type":"string"}
    },{
        "key":"content",
        "value":{"type":"string"}
    },{
        "key":"userId",
        "value":{"type":"string"}
    }
]
```

I need to know if there is an easy way to do this without ES6.

Comment: This is a very specific problem. It's not just flattening an array, it's normalizing data into a form only you know when it looks right. The question, therefore, is: What are the rules that define the target structure?

Comment: ... if one sticks to the OP's request of - ***I only need objects that have shallow key-values*** - one does end up with a list of  `{ "type": "string" }` since this is the only shallow substructure; `{ "key":"userId", "value":
 { "type": "string" } }` already is too complex. Or what does ***shallow key-values*** mean?

Comment: I mean all objects that have a type, my problem is I want to validate the types and they can be primitive like string or number or array or object, and they could also be user defined types so I need to find them all, and then validate them. @PeterSeliger

Comment: `request` and `response` at the provided data structure's first level do also feature `type`, but are not part of the example data for the expected result.

Comment: yes that's the problem, as I said in the question, the JSON can be irregular. containing objects and arrays, that I need to validate the objects that have the "type" field

Answer (score 1):

The next provided approach recursively walks any given data structure's property key-list while looking for a match with another key that needs to be provided.

In case of matching keys, the related/referred (sub)data structure will be collected via an additionally provided list.

In case of any (sub)data structure being an array, each of its data items will be recursively processed as well.

In case of any (sub)data structure being of none string type, the process starts a new recursion as described at the very beginning of this text.

```js
var data = {
 "name": "getPost",
 "request": {
  "type": "object",
  "fields": [{
   "key": "id",
   "value": {
    "type": "string"
   }
  }]
 },
 "response": {
  "type": "object",
  "fields": [{
   "key": "post",
   "value": {
    "type": "object",
    "fields": [{
     "key": "id",
     "value": {
      "type": "string"
     }
    }, {
     "key": "title",
     "value": {
      "type": "string"
     }
    }, {
     "key": "content",
     "value": {
      "type": "string"
     }
    }, {
     "key": "userId",
     "value": {
      "type": "string"
     }
    }]
   }
  }]
 },
 "error": []
};


function collectListOfAllSubTypeDataRecursivelyByKey(collector, key) {
  var
    itemKey = collector.key,
    data    = collector.data,
    list    = collector.list;

  if (Array.isArray(data)) {
    data.forEach(function (dataItem) {

      collector.list = list.concat(Object.keys(dataItem).reduce(collectListOfAllSubTypeDataRecursivelyByKey, {

        key:  itemKey,
        data: dataItem,
        list: []

      }).list);
    })
  } else {
    if (key === itemKey) {

      list.push(data);
    }
    if (typeof (data = data[key]) !== 'string') {

      collector.list = list.concat(Object.keys(data).reduce(collectListOfAllSubTypeDataRecursivelyByKey, {

        key:  itemKey,
        data: data,
        list: []

      }).list);
    }

  }
  return collector;
}


var subTypeList = Object.keys(data).reduce(collectListOfAllSubTypeDataRecursivelyByKey, {

  key:  'type',
  data: data,
  list: []

}).list;


subTypeList.forEach(function (type) {
  console.log('type : ', type);
});
// console.log('subTypeList : ', subTypeList);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

For the processed data structure, as provided by the OP, there will be a list that references 8 items of sup- and sub- data-structures each featuring a `type` property as it was ask for. Thus reflecting kind of a flattened list of this 8 items.